# Check whether a driver is installed for my USB device

Tags: c, windows, winapi, device, device-driver

I used `SetupDiGetClassDevs()`, `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo()` and `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()` to enumerate my USB device and check whether my device is available or not.

How can I check whether my proper driver is installed for my device or not?
Is there any APIs available to check this?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144063/check-if-a-windows-driver-exists-for-a-given-device-id/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the driver information for the device and then check against that, if your driver is installed and up-to-data.

Here is a bit of C++ code which might help you:

```
bool fetchDriverDescription( const std::wstring& driverRegistryLocation, tDriverDescription& desc )
{
    bool    rval = false;

    std::wstring regFolder = L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Class\\";
    regFolder += driverRegistryLocation;
    win32::registry::reg_key hKey = 
        win32::registry::reg_key::open( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, regFolder, KEY_READ );
    if( hKey )
    {
        if( win32::registry::read( hKey, L"ProviderName", desc.DriverProviderName, false ) != ERROR_SUCCESS )
            return false;

        desc.InstalledDriverRegFolder = regFolder;

        std::wstring val;
        if( win32::registry::read( hKey, L"DriverVersion", val, false ) == ERROR_SUCCESS )
            desc.Version = val;
        rval = true;
    }
    return rval;
}

std::wstring driverRegLocation;
if( fetchStringFromDiGetDevice( hDevInfo, DeviceInfo, SPDRP_DRIVER, driverRegLocation ) )
{
    bSuccessful = fetchDriverDescription( driverRegLocation, dev.DriverDesc );
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you go for `ControlSet001` instead of `CurrentControlSet`?

Comment: It would probably be better to use [`SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551967(v=vs.85).aspx), which you're already doing.  The only thing you should borrow from this answer is the name of the properties to read: `ProviderName` and `DriverVersion`.