# Why can't I find cfgmgr32.lib in the Windows SDK?

Tags: windows, device-driver

I'm trying to use the Configuration Manager API, e.g., [CM_Get_Device_ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff538405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The documentation says to link to `cfgmgr32.lib`.

However, when I do this, I get an error message from the linker:

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'cfgmgr32.lib'

I can't find `cfgmgr32.lib` anywhere in the Windows SDK.

If I leave out `cfgmgr32.lib` I get unresolved external symbol errors.

How can I use the Configuration Manager API?

Comment: That's odd. A downvote on a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the version of the Windows SDK you are using does not contain `cfgmgr32.lib`, you should link to `setupapi.lib` instead.  This contains the Configuration Manager functions.

Note that (depending on what you are doing) it may be preferable to use the more recent [Setup API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff550897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of the Configuration Manager API.

Comment: Well, it seems that these days [MS is encouraging to shift to the CM API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/porting-from-setupapi-to-cfgmgr32) instead...

Comment: CM APIs are available on all Windows SKUs and SetupAPI is only available on desktop based SKUs.  You might also consider using an umbrella lib like onecore.lib or onecoreuap.lib.