# Windows USB device refresh in C\C++

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I am trying to find a way to pragmatically re-enumerate the USB devices connected to the USB ports of PC.

In Windows, it is possible to open the Device Manager, then right click on the PC name and select "Scan for Hardware Changes".

How can I execute this (or something similar but specific to the USB bus) from a C/C++ program?

Comment: MSDN: [How To Force Reenumeration of a Device Tree From an Application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/259697)

Comment: How can I use CM_Locate_DevNode function?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539763(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Linking time there is an Linking error like LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Cfgmgr32.lib'

Comment: This will fix it http://stackoverflow.com/a/27178970/4603670 , ps `CM_Reenumerate_DevNode` needs admin access

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cfgmgr32.lib` library in your project. It's easy. If you don't know how to use it, you can ask me again.

```
BOOL ScanForHardwareChanges() 
{
    DEVINST     devInst;
    CONFIGRET   status;

   // 
   // Get the root devnode.
   // 

   status = CM_Locate_DevNode(&devInst, NULL, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);

   if (status != CR_SUCCESS) {
       printf("CM_Locate_DevNode failed: %x\n", status);
       return FALSE;
   }

   status = CM_Reenumerate_DevNode(devInst, 0);

   if (status != CR_SUCCESS) {
       printf("CM_Reenumerate_DevNode failed: %x\n", status);
       return FALSE;
   }

   return TRUE;
}
```