# How to check if USB CDC driver is installed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, driver, cdc

I need to install USB CDC driver (com port) to customers pc so my c++ mfc application works correctly. On windows 8 & 10 the driver is pre-installed, the problem is older verions of windows.

I have the driver from silabs, there is .cat, .inf and .exe files. After opening the installer - it just says **"Silicon Laboratories. Inc. (usbser) Ports (03/26/2014 6.1.7601.17514) - Ready to use"** after confirming the terms, nothing else.

I tried [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-device-drivers-in-the-system) but there is no usbser.sys or something like that in the list. And also [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27144063/check-if-a-windows-driver-exists-for-a-given-device-id) but nothing like "USB\VID_1BA4&PID_0002" (which I found in .inf file) wasn't found. I also tried to search for ClassGUID (**4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318**) & class=ports in regedit. It's always found the same things, that's probably not what I'm looking for.

What should I look for? What parameter is important? Thanks.

**.inf file**

```
[Version]
Signature="$WINDOWS NT$"
Class=Ports
ClassGUID={4D36E978-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
Provider=%SILICONLABS%
DriverVer=03/26/2014,6.1.7601.17514
CatalogFile=SiLabs-CDC.cat

[Manufacturer]
%SILICONLABS%=DeviceList, NT, NTAMD64, NTIA64

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[DeviceList]
%CDCDEVICE_1BA4_0002%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_1BA4&PID_0002
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0008&MI_02
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0008&MI_02

[DeviceList.NT]
%CDCDEVICE_1BA4_0002%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_1BA4&PID_0002
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0008&MI_02
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0008&MI_02

[DeviceList.NTAMD64]
%CDCDEVICE_1BA4_0002%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_1BA4&PID_0002
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0008&MI_02
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0008&MI_02

[DeviceList.NTIA64]
%CDCDEVICE_1BA4_0002%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_1BA4&PID_0002
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0003%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0003
%CDCDEVICE_2544_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_2544&PID_0008&MI_02
%CDCDEVICE_10C4_0008_02%=DriverInstall,USB\VID_10C4&PID_0008&MI_02

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[DriverInstall]
Include=mdmcpq.inf
CopyFiles=FakeModemCopyFileSection
AddReg=SerialPropPageAddReg

[DriverInstall.Services]
Include=mdmcpq.inf
AddService = usbser, 0x00000002, DriverServiceInst

[DriverServiceInst]
DisplayName=%SERVICE%
ServiceType=1
StartType=3
ErrorControl=1
ServiceBinary=%12%\usbser.sys

[SerialPropPageAddReg]
HKR,,EnumPropPages32,,"MsPorts.dll,SerialPortPropPageProvider"

;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Strings]
SILICONLABS = "Silicon Laboratories, Inc."
CDCDEVICE_1BA4_0002 = "Silicon Labs CDC Serial port"
CDCDEVICE_2544_0003 = "Silicon Labs CDC Serial port"
CDCDEVICE_10C4_0003 = "Silicon Labs CDC Serial port"
CDCDEVICE_2544_0008_02 = "Silicon Labs CDC Serial port"
CDCDEVICE_10C4_0008_02 = "Silicon Labs CDC Serial port"
SERVICE   = "USB CDC Serial Port Driver"
```

Comment: Try this:  "msinfo32 /report msiout.txt", the information it generates may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code sample you use is [Enumerating All Device Drivers in the System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-device-drivers-in-the-system)(loaded drivers).

I test with a FTDI USB-to-UART device. With the device attached to PC (driver loaded in memory) I can list related drivers like below, otherwise I can't.

[image]

So trying to attach the USB CDC device and try again.

**Update based on comment: "But where I can find if the driver is already signed or not, that's the question."**

Right click the *.sys file of the driver and check the digital signatures tab.

[image]

Comment: Nothing changed. The usbser.sys should be installed on every windows, but only windows 10 have it "signed" by .inf file, in older versions of windows I need to sign it by myself using custom .inf file. But where I can find if the driver is already signed or not, that's the question.

Comment: @ТомасПетр Please check my update answer to see if it helps.

Comment: Now I can see it. After attach the device to the computer, the "usbser.sys" shows up in loaded drivers. It's there any way to check it without connecting the device? That would be very nice.