# How can I find out if a USB device driver is installed by querying the registry?

Tags: windows, usb, driver, device-driver

I am trying to check if drivers are installed for a particular USB device as part of an installation process. Unfortunately the manufacturer has several different installers for the same driver and there seems to be no consistent place in the registry to check if the driver is installed.   However it's obvious that Windows *must* know if a driver is installed for a given USB device ID (Eg VID and PID) and I presume this is recorded in the registry?

How can I check to see if the driver is installed only by querying the registry, without relying on looking for installer-specific keys such as references to the uninstaller (which is unreliable) or calling Windows API functions?

Answer (score 1):

Don't query the registry. There's no documented location for this, and it changes. Definitely between versions, possibly with service packs.

The proper way is to use Windows API functions, and it's unclear why you would reject this solution.

Comment: I have no access to Windows API functions within the installer script (AFAIK).  I can only do basic things like check for the existence of files or registry keys.

Comment: That's going to be a problem, then. There are no ways to call an external DLL or EXE? How would you install the VC++ redist package, from your install script?

Comment: I'm not sure you could necessarily find this information in the registry anyway.  When a new device is connected, Windows looks inside .inf files to identify which if any of the installed drivers is applicable.

Comment: @MSalters I can't access the Windows Setup API from my installer, so is there a way to query which drivers are installed from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same Problem as you as I wanted to check in Installshield if a device driver was already installed.

I first tried the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\` path as mentioned in [USB Device Registry Entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-device-specific-registry-settings), and it worked on 2 Windows 10 systems I tried but on a 3rd System it was **not** located here anymore but in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceMigration\Devices\USB\`, I assume it has with a Windows 10 update to do but I am not sure…

I finally found out, that on **all** Systems I was able to find the VID/PID text (in my case VID_0483&PID_DF11) in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class`, which is pretty much what people programmatically do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190241/check-whether-a-driver-is-installed-for-my-usb-device) .

Anyway as MSaters suggested I would rather use a C# Windows query like `System.Management.SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver");` (see [How to check whether a driver is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23327660/how-to-check-whether-a-driver-is-installed)) as I am not sure, that the registry query allways work but it is in my case not possible.

**Edit:**

I found out, that Windows creates the registry entry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\` as soon as the device is connected, even without drivers installed, that means that it is an incorrect way to check if the driver is installed.

There is another way though, the registry entry contains "VID_XXXX&PID_YYYY" then a "SERIAL" as subfolder, in my case (VID=1FC9, PID=000C, SERIAL=ABCD) `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\VID_1FC9&PID_000C\ABCD`, you can then check the presence of an entry called `Driver`, it seems like it is only created after you install your Driver.

And for some reason the entry to look for under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceMigration\Devices\USB\VID_1FC9&PID_000C\ABCD` seems not to be `Driver` but `DriverInfName`